# MySQL Procedure to CREATE multiple tables is not working (WHILE loop dynamic SQL)

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have added a stored procedure to create multiple tables in dynamic SQL using WHILE loop in MySQL Workbench. The query creates last table only, instead of all. I have checked with drop table to delete the if table exists. But it still show already exists. Here is the query.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `weeklyLooper`(IN weeklycount INT)
BEGIN

SET @count = 0;
SET @weeklylooper = weeklycount;
SET @dumpclear =  CONCAT('week' , @weeklylooper);

WHILE @count <= @weeklylooper DO
set @count = @count+1;
SET @weeklyname =  CONCAT('week' , @count);
SET @weekly =  CONCAT('total_' , @weeklyname, '_deposits');

SET @dropquery = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `', @weeklyname, '`');
PREPARE droptablequery FROM @dropquery; 
EXECUTE droptablequery; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE droptablequery; 

SET @selectquery = CONCAT('CREATE temporary TABLE ', @weeklyname ,' AS SELECT sum(deposits) As ', @weekly,'  FROM base0');

PREPARE selecttablequery FROM @selectquery; 
EXECUTE selecttablequery; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE selecttablequery;

END WHILE;

END
```

Please help me to complete this.

Comment: A typo. `weeklyname` and `weeeklyname`. [How to debug](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=39ea595cadeb8d89b2485648e727f71f).

Comment: PS. Never type variables/columns names into DEBUG query - only copy-paste from definite place.

Comment: I have changed it. But still the issues are not rectified

Comment: See edited [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=604e29224c06b5b4031eb902cf1ae84e) and check does the queries are correct. I think that CREATE statements must contain some WHERE clause... The best way is to post the task additionally - what do you have (table `base0` - its structure and sample data) and what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I need to achieve two different results based on two table records, base0 is a temporary table with joins and some calculations. Client doesn't want to affect his database by creating extra tables. The result are weekly and monthly Cohorts based on the those two tables with lots of calculations. Actually I can't show the calculations here, it is confidential. All the calculations are done manually (weekly 30 tables, monthly 30 tables), for now I need to optimize this logic into looping using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating temporary tables - temporary tables only exist for the extent of the session - since every exec is in a unique session AND DIFFERS from the session you are running the procedure in the temporary tables are never available to the session in which you are running the procedure...

or as the manual says 'You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY table is visible only within the current session, and is dropped automatically when the session is closed.' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-temporary-table.html

Consider creating permanent tables and deleting them when you are done.

Comment: You said that every time a prepare, execute statement run, it will make the session ends. Thanks for the solution. I think, it is the issue. Friend, Can you please advice me to keep it working. Because I need to create temporary tables, I can't create tables. Client requirement is that. Shall I try this logic? Concatenate all the table in one query and execute them at once. Will this logic create required output?

Comment: No, session==connection. If you perform next calculation in the same connection then temporary tables are available. But if client reconnects due to some reason, the tables will be dropped.

Comment: @Akina do you have a reference?

Comment: I can run the query but i have lost connection issues. Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: @TamilSelvans *I can run the query but i have lost connection issues* If this happens then forget about all temporary tables created before - they're lost.

Comment: *do you have a reference?* A reference to what precisely? to "session==connection"? Try to imagine something else... To temptables drop? Simply test...

Comment: yes my friend, Now it is working. Modified the query. Thanks all